# Why are kendo grid pager controls getting duplicated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a very wired problem.

My kendo grid pager controls are getting rendered twice after I updated kendo files.

Someone knows something about this. I'm using Kendo for ASP.NET MVC.[Here you have an image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dCjx.png)

The second group of buttons are the ones that works. Buttons to the right and left of the pagination numbers are blocked.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Monibyte.Arquitectura.Presentacion.Transaccional.Dto.Tarjetas.PocMovimientosTarjeta>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .ColumnMenu()        
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("OndataBound"))
    .Events(e => e.DataBinding("OnDataBinding"))
    .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(Html.DefaultPageSizes()))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.IdMovimiento).Title("").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(50)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "detAdic_ListMov" }).IncludeInMenu(false)
            .HeaderTemplate(Html.GridCheckAll()).ClientTemplate(Html.GridCheck() +
                Html.GenericGridBtn("IncluirDetalleMovimiento", "ConsultaMovimientos", null,
                    altText: @RecEtiquetas.App_AgregarMovimiento,
                    jsparams: new
                    {
                        targetId = "detalleMovimiento",
                        dataFunc = "editarDataFunc",
                        callback = "editarCallback"
                    },
                    imageUrl: "imagenes/iconos/list(16).png",
                    authorizeFunc: "validaSegregar").ToHtmlString())
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "detAdic_ListMov", @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_AgregarMovimiento });
        columns.Bound(p => p.NumTarjeta).Title(RecEtiquetas.Mod_NumTarjeta).Hidden(true).Width(50)
            .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= templateDescripcionTarjeta(value) #")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.Mod_NumTarjeta });
        columns.Bound(p => p.NumReferencia).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_Referencia).Width(30)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_Referencia });
        columns.Bound(p => p.FecMovimiento).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_FechaMovimiento).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:$monibyte.formatDate(FecMovimiento)#")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_FechaMovimiento });
        columns.Bound(p => p.FecTransaccion).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_FecConsumo).Hidden(true).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:$monibyte.formatDate(FecTransaccion)#")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_FecConsumo });
        columns.Bound(p => p.Descripcion).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_DescripcionMovimiento).Width(250)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_Descripcion });
        columns.Bound(p => p.MonDebLocal).Title(Html.EtiquetasCompania("RecGlobalizacion", "App_DebitoMonedaLocal").ToString()).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:SimboloMonedaLocal# #:$monibyte.formatNumber(MonDebLocal)#")
            .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#:templateMontoDebLocal(data)#")
            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha" })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha monto-grid", @title = Html.EtiquetasCompania("RecGlobalizacion", "App_DebitoMonedaLocal") });
        columns.Bound(p => p.MonCredLocal).Title(Html.EtiquetasCompania("RecGlobalizacion", "App_CreditoMonedaLocal").ToString()).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:SimboloMonedaLocal# #:$monibyte.formatNumber(MonCredLocal)#")
            .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#:templateMontoCredLocal(data)#")
            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha" })
           .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha monto-grid", @title = Html.EtiquetasCompania("RecGlobalizacion", "App_CreditoMonedaLocal") });
        columns.Bound(p => p.MonDebInter).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_DebitoDolares).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:SimboloMonedaInter# #:$monibyte.formatNumber(MonDebInter)#")
            .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#:templateMontoDebInter(data)#")
            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha" })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha monto-grid", @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_DebitoDolares });
        columns.Bound(p => p.MonCredInter).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_CreditoDolares).Width(40)
            .ClientTemplate("#:SimboloMonedaInter# #:$monibyte.formatNumber(MonCredInter)#")
            .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#:templateMontoCredInter(data)#")
            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha" })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alinearDerecha monto-grid", @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_CreditoDolares });
        columns.Bound(p => p.DescripcionMoneda).Title(RecEtiquetas.App_Moneda).Hidden(true).Width(40)
            .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate(RecEtiquetas.App_TotalRegistros + " #=value# = #=count#")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @title = @RecEtiquetas.App_Moneda });
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(Html.DefaultPageSize())
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(p => p.FecMovimiento).Descending())
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.MonCredLocal).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.MonDebLocal).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.MonCredInter).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.MonDebInter).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.DescripcionMoneda).Count();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.SimboloMonedaLocal).Min();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.SimboloMonedaInter).Min();
        })
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.DescripcionMoneda))
        .Read(read => read.Action("FiltrarMovimientos", "ConsultaMovimientos"))
    ))
```

Comment: I've got the same issue. What kendo version are you using, I've just noticed the glitch after upgrading to 2018.1.425.

Comment: I were using the latest version. I don't remember the exact version. I had to use the last 2017 version. Versions from 2018 were producing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Progress Telerik support and this is the answer they gave.

> We had reports about such an issue recently. The customers who encountered it had updated UI for ASP.NET MVC to the latest version
>   but forgot to update the Kendo UI script and CSS files, or vice versa.
>   Could you double check if you updated both the DLL and the JS and CSS
>   files? To check the current Kendo UI scripts version in your page, you
>   can call:

```js
console.log(kendo.version);
```

> To check the DLL version, open the References folder in your project,
>   right-click Kendo.Mvc and select Properties.
>
> The two versions have to match in order to have the widgets working
>   correctly

So check your dll and js/css versions match.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved my problem downgrading my kendo version to 2017, but when I was trying to solve this problem, I checked those files and they were updated. If I get the error again in a future try to update the kendo to the latest version, I would double check as you sad. Thak you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with kendo 2018.1.221. The issue was fixed when the jquery is loaded after the kendo javascript bundle

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2018.1.221/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo/2018.1.221/kendoscripts")
//jquery needs to be loaded after kendo scripts
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try this later.

Comment: The above changes load the pager correctly on screen but gives jquery errors. On further investigation the issue seems to be specific to 2018.1.221. Downgrading to 2018.1.117 or upgrading to latest 2018.2.516 fixes it.

Comment: See new (and my final) answer below

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I was getting duplicate paging was because the Kendo.MVC.dll in the project did not match the Kendo css & scripts version used by the bundles.

Remove the Kendo.Mvc dll in your project and re-add from the local path. eg.

```
\Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC R2 2018\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc4Kendo.Mvc.dll
```

(Same answer as Steven Anderson)